# How to add 2 same name frameworks into project

Tags: xcode

I have 2 frameworks, one for Debug and another one for Release
They have same name and i can't rename them
When i import one, it's adding to Embed Frameworks and i can use it, but when i'm adding second, it's adding to Embed Frameworks too and i getting problem `Multiple commands produce...`.
Is it real include different frameworks for Debug and Release builds?

I tried to use this shell script
But nothing happened

```
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
    cp -R "${PROJECT_DIR}/Debug/MyFramework.xcframework" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/MyFramework.xcframework"
else
    cp -R "${PROJECT_DIR}/Release/MyFramework.xcframework" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/MyFramework.xcframework"
fi
```

I also trying add Framework and Header Search Paths
When i use this realisation i getting `No such module 'MyFramework'`
Because i didnt added it to Embed Frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Previously, for static frameworks you could use the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS, where you just needed to point to the appropriate location for the appropriate configuration(DEBUG and RELEASE) in the project settings:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)/MyFramework.xcframework
```

But this does not seem to work for dynamic frameworks. One solution for this is to wrap the frameworks in to Pods.

**my-lib-debug.podspec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "my-lib-debug"
  s.ios.vendored_framework = 'framework/MyFramework.xcframework'
end
```

**my-lib-release.podspec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "my-lib-release"
  s.ios.vendored_framework = 'framework/MyFramework.xcframework'
end
```

**Application Podfile**

```
  pod 'my-lib-debug', :path => 'path/to/my-lib-debug', :configurations => ['Debug']
  pod 'my-lib-release', :path => 'path/to/my-lib-release', :configurations => ['Release']
```